# PySide and Python - How to browse a folder and write the file name?

Tags: python, pyside, qfiledialog

I would like to press a button and than open a file browser and write down selected file in a label. I have this function which I call when the button is pressed:

```
    @Slot()
    def browse_folder(self):
        self.fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.statusLabel.setText(self.fname)
```

However, I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setText' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setText(unicode, unicode)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QLabel.setText(unicode)
```

How do I convert `self.fname`, which holds selected file name, as unicode?

Comment: try `self.statusLabel.setText(str(self.fname))`

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a tuple (u'/path/to/file/file.csv', u") printed out. Can you tell me what is it the second empty `u''` for?

Comment: Not really sure, as [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) is written that it should return `QString`. I would suggest to only use the first element of the tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PySide docs are not brilliant on this.  But the easiest way to answer this sort of question is to build a little test harness.  Something like:

```
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui

def do_file():
    fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    print fname

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

button = QtGui.QPushButton("Test File")
button.clicked.connect(do_file)
button.show()

app.exec_()
```

Running this a little bit will show you that the static `getOpenFileName` method returns a tuple consisting of the filename first and the chosen filter second.  For example, by default, on my system this returns `('C:/Users/Myname/Documents/filename', 'All Files (*.*)')`.

So you then need to extract the first element of the tuple before calling `setText`.